# Strange errors after loading Quartz.framework Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, duplicates, state, quartz-graphics, appkit

in order to load a PDF document into a PDFView I added Quartz.framework to my project.

Since then, although I haven´t even used it so far, I´m getting strange error messages:
**Multiple methods named 'state' found with mismatched result, parameter type or attributes**

I´m using the **state** method which is from AppKit.framework/NSCell to check if checkboxes are on or off like this:

```
BOOL replaceCheckBoxFlag = ([sender state] == NSOnState);
```

The ImageCaptureCore.framework which is part of the Quartz.framework also owns a method **state**. How is it possible that Xcode get´s confused?

What can I do? Any hints?

Ronald

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because `sender` is declared as type `id`, which means that the compiler knows it's an Objective-C object, but it doesn't know what class it belongs to. So it looks though all the class definitions and it found two matches, and it doesn't know which one to use.

The solution is to either cast it or use a new variable of the correct type:

```
BOOL replaceCheckBoxFlag = ([(NSCell *)sender state] == NSOnState);
```

or

```
NSCell *cell = sender;
BOOL replaceCheckBoxFlag = ([cell state] == NSOnState);
```

Comment: Very well explained :) Thank you.

Comment: I wonder if Objective-C is able to realize what class sender is? Is there any enplanation for this?

Comment: @RonaldHofmann It has to make the determination at compile time, since it affects the code to be generated. Since it's a parameter to a method call, and the method could be called from anywhere (e.g., code you will link in later that the compiler can't see), it's impossible to know the type with 100% certainty.